# Should I marry someone who is not a virgin by premarital sex?

Tags: nikah

Recently my parents did matchmaking for me. After speaking with her, both the families and us have agreed on marriage.

However, I just came to learn from the bride-to-be that she had a relationship and she isn't a virgin. However, she told me it is already in her past.

Now it puts me in a great deal of dilemma. What does Islam say about that? I'm emotional at the moment but I want my religion to guide me through this to take the right decision. Please share your wisdom and proper references for my understanding.

Answer (score -1):

The fornicator does not marry except a [female] fornicator or polytheist, and none marries her except a fornicator or a polytheist, and that has been made unlawful to the believers.

*Surah An-Nur, 24:3*

Comment: Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Didn't you get the indication that she has repented?

Comment: Aboudi- I did not get any indication. If I get that, should I forgive her and carry on? How can I find it in my heart to do such act of forgiveness? Help me brothers with what our Quaran Sunnah say about forgiveness. However, I am also willing to guide her to repent for her sins if she hasn't already. Please help me here.

Comment: @Din0744 Allah the most merciful can forgive who ever he wants for what ever action they carried out (except shirk), whether you forgive her or not it does not make a difference as it has not caused you any harm.